# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is missing but a required field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database-cleaner

I'm upgrading a rails app thats using MongoDB starting at Rails 4.2 and MongoDB 3.4

Ruby version is 2.7.6
MongoDB is 3.7
Rails 5.2

I've updated the app from `database_cleaner` to `database_cleaner-mongoid`. In my `spec/rails_helper.rb` I call `DatabaseCleaner.clean` before every example.

I get this Error:

```
Failures:

  1) Testy McTesterson
     Failure/Error: DatabaseCleaner.clean

     Mongo::Error::OperationFailure:
       [40414:Location40414]: BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is missing but a required field (on localhost:27017, retries disabled)
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:125:in `clean_db'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/webmock.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

To be clear, I'm always getting this error. I moved to `database_cleaner-mongoid` hoping it would resolve it. I've tried 3.6-4.4 versions of MongoDB. I also used the debugger to step through the code to find that error and I lose the context when it enters the kernel. Hoping someone has suggestions on where to look or if they've experienced it before.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved with
Ruby 2.7.6
Mongoid 6.1.1
Rails 5.07.2
MongoDB 4.4